# ASK java levenberg-marquardt algorithm

Tags: java

i try to implement levenberg algorithm in java code, but i met some difficulties, i dont know whats the problems, but the number of MSE doesnt going down. i made this network with 1 hidden layer, 18 input's neurons, 7 hidden's neurons, and 3 output's neuron. these are formula i use to calculate jacobian matrix:

- b2=f'(yin)
- wjk=b2*zj
- din=sum(b2*wjk)
- b1=din*f'(zin)
- vij=b1*xi

all of it, will be save in jacobian matriks

```
j[iteration][]={vij,b1,wjk,b2}
```

to get network error, which will be multiply with jacobian transpose to find it's gradient i used this code:

```
public double err(int[]t,double[]y){
    double err=0;
    for(int z=0;z<out;z++){
        err+=t[z]-y[z];
    }return err;
}
```

and to calculate the MSE of this network i used this code:

```
public double mse(int[]t,double[]y){
    double mse=0;
    for(int z=0;z<out;z++){
        mse+=Math.pow(t[z]-y[z],2);
    }return mse;

}
```

both error and MSE function i called when iterate all data input, and sum of all MSE will be divide with sum of data input.

Comment: I don't immediately see anything here that looks like an implementation of the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm. For one thing, LM is an iterative algorithm and I can't see any iteration code here. Could you explain a) what each of these functions is intended to do, b) what each of the parameters means and c) where the mean squared error is calculated in this code? For us to help, it would also be valuable to see an example of the data that you're fitting and the equation that you're fitting to those data.